# How to properly update value when user clicks checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, symfony, checkbox

I'm having an issue updating a value when the user clicks on a checkbox. If the user clicks once the value is added properly, however if the user makes quick consecutive clicks on the same checkbox, the value isn't added (or subracted when deselected) properly. The values get doubled. Is there a way to set up a timer on clicks for the checkbox or maybe a better way to add the values?

Here's the jquery with ajax:

```
function reconcile(glid) 
{
    var reconcile = 1;
    var debit = $('#debit' + glid).val() * 1;
    var credit = $('#credit' + glid).val() * 1;
    var outstanding = $('#outstanding').val() * 1;
    var reconciled = $('#reconciled').val() * 1;
    var difference = $('#difference').val() * 1;


    if($('#checkbox' + glid).prop('checked') === true) reconcile = 1;
    else if($('#checkbox' + glid).prop('checked') === false) reconcile = 0;

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Ledger/UpdateReconciled/' + glid + '/' + reconcile,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            if (data == 1) 
            {
                $('#text' + glid).html('Reconciled');

                $('#reconciled').val(reconciled *1 + debit *1 - credit *1);
                $('#outstanding').val(outstanding *1 - debit *1 + credit *1);
            }
            else if (data == 0) 
            {
                $('#text' + glid).html('Outstanding');
                $('#reconciled').val(reconciled *1 - debit *1 + credit *1);
                $('#outstanding').val(outstanding *1 + debit*1 - credit*1);
            }
            updateDifference();
        } ,
        error :function() 
        {
            alert(data);
        } 
    });
}
```

And here's the html:

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}

<table class="jtable" id='dattable'>
<caption class="ui-widget ui-widget-header">Bank Ledger</caption>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style='width: 15%;' class='ui-state-default'>Account</th>
        <th style='width: 15%;' class='ui-state-default'>Date</th>
        <th style='width: 25%;' class='ui-state-default'>Reference</th>
        <th style='width: 15%;' class='ui-state-default'>Note</th>
        <th style='width: 15%;' class='ui-state-default'>Debit</th>
        <th style='width: 15%;' class='ui-state-default'>Credit</th>
        <th style='width: 15%;' class='ui-state-default'>Balance</th>
        <th style='width: 15%;' class='ui-state-default'></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% set outstanding = 0 %}
    {% set reconciled = 0 %}
{% for record in records %}
    {% if (record.reconciled == 1) %}
        {% set reconciled = reconciled + record.debit - record.credit %}
    {% elseif (record.reconciled == 0) %}
        {% set outstanding = outstanding + record.debit - record.credit %}
    {% endif %}
    <tr>
        <td class='ui-widget-content'>{{ record.account.number }}</td>
        <td class='ui-widget-content'>{{ record.date|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
        <td class='ui-widget-content'>{{ record.entry }} | {{ record.reference }}</td>
        <td class='ui-widget-content'>{{ record.note }}</td>
        <td class='ui-widget-content'><input id='debit{{ record.id }}' type='hidden'    value='{{ record.debit }}'>{{ record.debit|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>
        <td class='ui-widget-content'><input id='credit{{ record.id }}' type='hidden' value='{{ record.credit }}'>{{ record.credit|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>
        <td class='ui-widget-content'><input id='checkbox{{ record.id }}' onclick='reconcile({{ record.id }});' type='checkbox'{% if record.reconciled == true %} checked='checked'{% endif %}></td>
        <td class='ui-widget-content'><div id='text{{ record.id }}'>{% if record.reconciled == true %}Reconciled{% else %}Outstanding{% endif %}</div></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <td class='ui-widget-content list_total'>Account Balance</td>
    <td class='ui-widget-content list_total'>Outstanding: <input id='outstanding' type='number' value='{{ outstanding }}' readonly></td>
    <td class='ui-widget-content list_total'>Reconciled: <input id='reconciled' type='number' value='{{ reconciled }}' readonly></td>
    {% set difference = balance + reconciled %}
    <td class='ui-widget-content list_total' colspan='3'>Difference: <input id='difference' type='number' value='{{ difference }}' readonly></td>
    <td class='ui-widget-content list_total'>{{ balance|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}      </td>
    </tr>


</tfoot>
</table>
    <button type='submit' id='postEntries' name='postEntries' value = 'true'>Post</button>
</form>
```

I'm using Symfony, if you're wondering about the syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated and let me know if you need any more info. Thanks!

Comment: I would probably just disable the checkbox or block the UI while the ajax request is running.

Comment: Any suggestions on how you think I should go about doing this? I've looked into the Jquery BlockUI Plugin. Think that would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the ajax call, add

```
$('#checkbox' + glid).attr("disabled", true);
```

In the success and error block of the ajax call, add:

```
$('#checkbox' + glid).removeAttr("disabled");
```

This will disable the checkbox until the ajax request is done

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did exactly what I needed. However, I noticed that if the user selected multiple checkboxes quickly, the same problem occurred. I fixed this by disabling all checkboxes and re-enabling all checkboxes after the ajax call. Thanks for the advice.